# ViewController return results to the ViewController which calls it

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I want to open New **ViewController-B** from **ViewController-A**

Then after Close **ViewController-B** it return **Some Value (Result)** to the **ViewController-A**

is it possible Without using notification?

if Yes then How?

Comment: use delegate or unwind segue

Comment: check this: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unwind-segues-as-an-alternative-to-delegation/

Comment: are your controllers embedded in UINavigationController ?

Comment: Yes ViewController-A  embedded UINavigationController

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many, many times

Answer (score 0):

More "clean" way of doing this is to use Delegate pattern.
The steps to implement this pattern:

1. Declare protocol in your ViewController-B, for example:

   ```
    protocol ViewControllerAUpdatingProtocol: class {

        func update(withSomeValue someValue: SomeValueType)

    }
   ```

   Make it class-only since we know that ViewController-A class object will conform to it.
2. Add "delegate" property to your ViewController-B:

   ```
   weak var delegate: ViewControllerAUpdatingProtocol!
   ```

   In case ViewController-A does not necessarily have to be updated you can make this property optional:

   ```
   weak var delegate: ViewControllerAUpdatingProtocol?
   ```
3. Now call "update" method of your delegate from the place you close ViewController-B.

   ```
   delegate.update(withSomeValue: yourValue)
   ```
4. Then conform ViewController-A to protocol ViewControllerAUpdatingProtocol:

   ```
   extension ViewControllerA: ViewControllerAUpdatingProtocol {
        func update(withSomeValue someValue: SomeValueType) {
             // your implementation goes here
        }
    }
   ```
5. Initialize "delegate" property of ViewController-B in
   ViewController-A:

   ```
       viewControllerBInstance.delegate = self
   ```